# How to stop the program when the output fills the screen in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line-interface

How can I get the status of the terminal from a Python program? I want the program to stop printing lines to the screen when the screen is full and wait for user input.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest (no code) way to accomplish that is to pipe your program's output through a pager program like `less` or `more` (assuming *nix), like:

#### infinity.py

```
import random

while 1:
   print random.randint(0, 0xffffffff)
```

#### command line

```
python infinty.py | less
```

...gives output like:

```
848605718
899092472
2576425641
3098821373
259379057
164782822
416064876
2488878735
1216764788
2682214542
531576871
2175787865
869960770
:
```

...and waits for user input.

Comment: The Windows command line also has [more](http://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm). For example,`python myscript.py | more -C` should work. While `less` is nicer, it's not available on Windows by default. You could try [Less for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm) though. But +1 :)

Comment: Ah, cool -- I thought I only had it on Windows because I have cygwin installed.

Comment: Doing it this way results in some wonkiness.  If you put a `sleep` in the loop, `less` outputs nothing until the script has printed enough values to fill the terminal.  If you return a string with line breaks from `sys.exit()` (or, I would bet, if you `print` a string containing line breaks), `less` will print the whole string to the terminal at once, no matter how many lines it is.  If you end `less` with `q` at any time before your python code has finished, your code will exit prematurely with an exception.  I wouldn't recommend this for anything other than trivially simple examples.

Comment: This is a nice shortcut but as sr2222 pointed out, it might be buggy.

Answer (score 2):

If you need more control over the terminal window, and assuming you're on Linux/*BSD/MacOSX, then you will need to use [curses](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html) for that. This is just a simple example:

```
import curses
stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.getmaxyx() #returns the width and height of the terminal screen
stdscr.getyx()    #returns the current x,y position.
```

You should check the library [reference](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html) for more functions.